# Is the angular momentum conserved?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics

A wheel is mounted vertically and a mass $m$ is placed on it. The position of the mass makes an angle with respect to the vertical axis (that is $\Theta \neq 0$ or $\neq 180$). Therefore, gravity will make the wheel and the mass start rotating (this is like a simple pendulum). My confusion is that

Is the angular momentum conserved? the initial condition is $t = 0$, $\theta = \theta_0$

The radius of the wheel is $R$ and its mass is $M$

I know that the mass and the wheel will start rotating faster and fastest at the very bottom. So L = r x pv cannot be constant right? because r = R and v is changing

Comment: what is a "vertical" wheel? Perhaps specify the direction of the axis?

Comment: I mean the wheel is not lying on the surface. You can think of it like a bicycle wheel that is not touching the ground.

Comment: I understood it as having it's rotational axis placed horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

Angular momentum is not conserved, as it is not a closed system. The mass is being pulled downwards by the Earth due to gravity and the angle changes with time, thus also changing the applied torque.

However, energy is conserved. It changes from potential (at start) to kinetic (at the very bottom; theta = 0) to potential again (when it swings back up again). Angular momentum is conserved, only when there is no tangential force applied.